# Node JS same request works on localhost but not on aws ec2 server

Tags: node.js, http, express, amazon-ec2

I am new to backend programming and have this problem with a GET request for retrieving data when logged in as a user.

I get the data fine on my localhost server with status code 200, but same GET request doesn't give back data from the server on aws EC2.

I have been looking around for a solution but it seems like I am missing some crucial info that I can't wrap my head around.

[localhost dev server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYpgQ.png)
[ec2 aws server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMwI6.png)

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.userId) {
        return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/index.html'))
    }
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/login.html'))
})

router.get('/data', function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.session.userId)
        .exec(function (error, user) {
            res.send(user)
        }
    );
})
```

it's only the /data request that's acting weird.

Comment: In the ec2 screenshot, the error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` in `app.js` line 41. Can you provide that code?

Comment: don't worry about it, it's unrelated. That's some other front end issue

Comment: For ec2 server, the `/data` response is `304 Modified`. It's pretty normal -- `GET /data` request was sent before, and after revalidation, server says "it's not changed, just use the cache in browser". Can you explain what does "doesn't get a response from the server" mean?

Comment: if you look at the first picture, I am receiving some data but not in the second picture. That's the issue

Comment: Well, I believe the data is returned (from cache). It's not printed in console because there is an uncaught error thrown, which leads frontend to unpredictable status. Can you fix that error and try again?

Comment: Can you show how do responses look like for both requests (local and EC2)?

Comment: i fixed the error and still no response. By no response I mean that when you look at the response tab in networks, it's empty

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this line to my axios request `withCredentials: true`